# can any body help me abt sql procedures for modifing a csv file from the contents of the table

Tags: oracle

Hi i stuck at writing a procedure which have to update the csv file (or delete the old csv file and creating the new csv file with same name and data in table)based on the contents of the table..

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 1):

Hi the Oracle UTL_FILE utility would be good to use, here is 2 procedures I use

1. Delete file 

2. Create a CSV file from any query string passed in as a parameter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  delete_external_file (p_directory in VARCHAR2
                                                    ,p_filename in VARCHAR2) 
AS

BEGIN

  utl_file.fremove(p_directory
,p_filename);

EXCEPTION

  when others then raise;

END;
```

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  dump_table_to_csv( p_query in varchar2
                                             ,  p_dir   in varchar2
                                             ,  p_filename in varchar2)
 is

     l_output        utl_file.file_type;

     l_theCursor     integer default dbms_sql.open_cursor;

     l_columnValue   varchar2(2000);

     l_status        integer;

     l_colCnt        number := 0;

     l_separator     varchar2(1);

     l_descTbl       dbms_sql.desc_tab;

 begin

    l_output := utl_file.fopen( p_dir, p_filename, 'w',32760 );
    execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'' ';
    dbms_sql.parse(  l_theCursor,  p_query, dbms_sql.native );
    dbms_sql.describe_columns( l_theCursor, l_colCnt, l_descTbl );
    for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
    utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator || '"' || l_descTbl(i).col_name || '"' );
    dbms_sql.define_column( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue, 4000 );
    l_separator := ',';
    end loop;
    utl_file.new_line( l_output );
    l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);
    while ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_theCursor) > 0 ) loop
         l_separator := '';
         for i in 1 .. l_colCnt loop
              dbms_sql.column_value( l_theCursor, i, l_columnValue );
              utl_file.put( l_output, l_separator||'"'|| l_columnValue||'"' );
              l_separator := ',';
          end loop;
          utl_file.new_line( l_output );
      end loop;
     dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
     utl_file.fclose( l_output );
     execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
exception

      when others then

          execute immediate 'alter session set nls_date_format=''dd-MON-yy'' ';
         raise;
 end;
```